# Why do so many people use me.projectname.main as package paths?

Tags: java, path, coding-style, package, convention

I have seen this so often and it confuses the hell out of me.

I always title the packages directly after what they are. For example the path to my Main class is never "me.myproject.main.Main.class" but only "main.Main.class" and so far I have never had problems with it.

However I have seen everyone doing it otherwise so often, that I wonder: Is that really just a meaningless convention (like for (int i = 0...)) or does it actually have practical use adding all that, that just isn't apparent to me?

Comment: If you ask me, as an independent programmer, it doesn't matter what you name your package. Unless you're sharing packages with other devs, and theres a chance you both might have the same name for a package, i find the convention to be a drag. Dont use default package (cant import from there) and you should be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packages are usually named using the reverse-domain name of an organization, ie. `com.example.projectname.Main.class`. If everyone were to name their packages `main.Main.class`, what would happen if you were using *my* code in *your* project? You would end up with conflicting `main.Main` classes.

Comment: That makes sense! I think I'll be doing it like that then.
Thanks.